# How to set index of elements generated by ng-repeat manually?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 ng-repeats like this

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items1" ng-if="i.name == 'abc'">
    <input name="iName[{{$index}}].ele" value="" />
</div>
<div ng-repeat="i in items2" ng-if="i.name == 'abc'">
    <input name="iName[{{$index}}].ele" value="" />
</div>
```

its generating output like this

```
<input name="iName[1].ele" value="" />
<input name="iName[3].ele" value="" />
<input name="iName[1].ele" value="" />
```

How to fix the above code so that output is like this, see the indexes

```
<input name="iName[0].ele" value="" />
<input name="iName[1].ele" value="" />
<input name="iName[2].ele" value="" />
```

Comment: what are the contents of the items1 and items2 arrays?

Comment: content is like [{name: 'abc', type: 'zy'}... ]

Comment: maybe the ng-if is preventing some of the inputs from showing, are the indexes correct if you remove the ng-if?

Comment: Yes, If I remove the ng-if indexes are correct.

Comment: Are you sure items1[0].name and items1[2].name are 'abc'? That would be the only reason I can think of that it's not displaying correctly when you add the ng-if.

Comment: please check the demo here, its generating the index 1,3,1. But I want 0,1,2, see http://plnkr.co/edit/ewOcHKnmgOaKMHxFsRnA

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to be too smart in the view. The better way would be to add some controller code, that pulls the filtered items into an array and then outputs that array. See this 
http://plnkr.co/edit/G1npriGYeYKGIx94QqTG?p=preview

Something like

```
 angular.forEach($scope.items1,function(item){
      if(item.name=='abc') $scope.filtereditems.push(item);
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.items2,function(item){
      if(item.name=='abc') $scope.filtereditems.push(item);
    });
```

Now you can bind to `filteredItems`

Comment: Yes, but in my specifc case I dont want to create a filtered item. THe point here is there no simple way to handle a global counter???

Comment: As i said i, believe you are trying to be too smart in view, you views should be simple. You can use expressions for assignment in view, but since expression are evaluated multiple time the result is in determinant.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-if is re-evaluated each iteration of the loop so your code is hiding every input where i.name != 'abc'. If you want to display the $index value each iteration, you would need to put your ng-repeat and ng-if in seperate tags, something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in items1">
    $index = {{$index}}
    <input ng-if="i.name == 'abc'" name="iName[{{$index}}].ele" value="{{$index}}" />
  </div>
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2HKgnk